# How to combine 2 JavaScript code blocks

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to combine 2 JavaScript code blocks in in my footer but when I use both it gives an error. How do I combine 2 JavaScript code blocks?

**FIRST**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mydata').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        scrollY:        400,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         true
    } );
} );
```

**SECOND**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mydata').DataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
        "sUrl": "js/dil/English.json",
        }
    } );
} );
```

Error message: DataTables warning: table id=mydata - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: "It gives error". What error?

Comment: If I use both in the same page It gives error

Comment: Yes but what is the error? What does it say?

Comment: @Andrew Added as a normal answer. `:)` You are welcome! ☺

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=mydata - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: @Andrew Doesn't the code work? You told it works?

Comment: It doesnt work when I use both. Only error message (Note: Your answer works, thank you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just JavaScript initialisation objects. Just combine the objects:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mydata').DataTable({
    "order": [
      [0, "desc"]
    ],
    scrollY: 400,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: true,
    "oLanguage": {
      "sUrl": "js/dil/English.json",
    }
  });
});
```

This should be working. You need to clearly tell what's the error coming up.